# How to return from AJAX wrapper function

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var wrapper = function() {

   var condition; //boolean  

   $.get('url', function(data) {

      console.log(data); //url
      condition = true/false;

   });

  return condition; 
}
```

when I do `wrapper()` it returns always `undefined` because of async nature of `$.get`. How to I solve this issue?

Comment: Solve it by not returning anything, and putting all logic in to the callback function, either directly or by calling some processing functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not rather do something like this and use callbacks

```
var wrapper = function(callback) {

    var condition; //boolean  

    $.get('url', function(data) {

        console.log(data); //url
        condition = true/false;
        callback(condition);
    });

}

wrapper(function(condition){
    //do something with the returned condition
});
```

If you give more details I can expand this to help you further

Answer (score 2):

When using asynchronous operations you do not return anything. Instead send a callback function as argument to `wrapper` function.

```
var wrapper = function(callback) {
   var condition; //boolean  
   $.get('url', function(data) {
      condition = true/false;
      callback(condition);
   });
}

wrapper(function(condition) {
   // check condition
});
```